# Checking if sge is true or false in assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I am new to MIPS assembly and I am trying to check if my 'sge' operation returned true or false, would this be a valid way to check this (using 1 for true and zero for false)?

```
sge $t1, $c, $a
beq $t1, 1, TRUE
beq $t1, 0, FALSE
TRUE: add $s0, $s1, 1
FALSE: sub $s0, $s1, 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`beq <register>,<immediate value>, label` is **not** a legal MIPS instruction. Real MIPS instructions have only one field for an immediate value like a constant or a branch offset. (Some MIPS assemblers may implement this as a [pseudo instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#Pseudo_instructions)).

A more idiomatic way of writing this is:

```
  sge    $t1, $t2, $t3    # $t2 contains c, $t3 contains a
         # sge sets $t1 to 1 if $t2>=$t3 otherwise $t1 gets set to 0
  bnez   $t1, $zero, TRUE # goto TRUE if $t1 != 0
         # at this point we know that $t1==0, so we don't need a conditional branch
  b      FALSE
```